# Non-linear data preprocessing before mini-batch gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, classification, gradient-descent

I found some realisation of pretty interesting ML algorithm. https://github.com/EderSantana/DeepEEG We have dataset X, matrix of spacial filter W, matrix of time filter V, and matrices U and B - parameters of classyfier. 
$Xfilt_i=ln(W*(X_i*v)^2))$

$Z=(Xfilt)^T * U+B$

$Y\_pred = argmax(softmax(Z))$

So, quite simple logistic regression classification. But most inreresting thing was the way authors tune W,V,U and B  matrices. W was initialized by CSP algorith. V was initialized by ones, U and B by zeros. And then cross-entropy cost function optimised (mini-batch gradient descent) respect to this parameters. And accuracy, achived by this way pretty high. My quiestion is, why we need non-linearity here (squaring and log)

$Xfilt_i=ln(W*(X_i*v)^2))$
?

PS In experiments optimisation algorithm did not converge without this nonlineraity.

Comment: Please edit your post to link to the article.

Comment: Are we looking at [the same paper](http://cnel.ufl.edu/files/1429900003.pdf)? Eq. (1) uses a logistic, not a log nonlinearity, and there is no **convolution** after the $w$ matrix. And just to check, you are working on EEG classification, right?

Comment: Yep! BUT authors of this paper wrote one  thing in paper, and completely different in python implementation. Eq.(1) in their implementation become something  like
$Yprob = softmax(ln(W*(X*V)^{2})*U^{T}+B)$

Comment: Ask the authors.